# How to package sources in a jar in Netbeans for maven projects?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jar, packaging

When building maven projects (Java) in Netbeans, by default, sources are left out. 
**How to package sources in a jar in Netbeans for maven projects?**

Something like:

```
myproject.jar
myproject-sources.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways.

---

**First way** - *Project Properties*

1. Right click on the project > *Properties*
2. Go to > *Actions*
3. Either add a custom one (click *Add custom...*) for a separate action or add it to an existing one (e.g. Build with dependencies) by selecting it.
4. In the *Execute Goals* menu, add `source:jar`

### [image: Project Properties > Actions]

**Second way** - *Custom Goals*

1. Right click on the project > *Custom* > *Goals*
2. In Goals: type `source:jar`
3. To make this permanent, select the checkbox *Remember as* and give it a name.
4. Run it: Right click on the project > *Custom* > *`the name you selected`*

[image: Custom Goals]

### [image: Run custom goal]

> Note: For both ways, when you type source, Netbeans suggest many options, try them for other cool options!